# Connection pooling with python mysql-connector

Tags: mysql, python

I would like to use connection pooling with mysql-connector 2.1.5

On Ubuntu everything works fine, but I would like to switch to Alpine and have used [this file](https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-2.1.5.tar.gz) to install the connector (as described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-installation-source.html)).

The installation seems to work. I can use `mysql.connector.connection()`, but whenever I try `mysql.connector.pooling.MySQLConnectionPool()` I get the error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'pooling'`.

I have also tried creating a pool implicitly using `cnxpool = mysql.connector.connection(pool_name="...")` but I cannot get the connection. Everytime I try `cnx = cnxpool.get_connection()` I get the error `AttributeError: 'MySQLConnection' object has no attribute 'get_connection'`

Is there any way to use pooling with the platform independent install package, or is it just not implemented there?

Comment: How about never using pooling.  It is not a requirement, and it does not save much in _most_ environments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some experimentation in console trying to figure out why this was happening for me as well. In the end, I searched right into the file folder for the package looking to ensure that the pooling file was present in the `mysql.connector` package version I had.

Sure enough there it was.

In the end, I simply changed my import statement. I had been using

```
import mysql.connector
pool = mysql.connector.pooling.MySQLConnectionPool(**config)
```

After playing in console for a bit I realized that it would be happy if I just used;

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import pooling
pool = pooling.MySQLConnectionPool(**config)
```

Worked fine. Couldn't tell you "why", but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

you can create the connection pool using a MySQL Connector Python’s  `pooling.MySQLConnectionPool` and `pooling.PooledMySQLConnection` class provides the instantiation and management of connection pools.

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
from mysql.connector import pooling
try:
   connection_pool = mysql.connector.pooling.MySQLConnectionPool(pool_name="pool",
                                                              pool_size=1,
                                                              pool_reset_session=True,
                                                              host='yourHost',
                                                              database='mysql_db',
                                                              user='username',
                                                              password='password')
```

Please refer  - [Python connection Pooling](https://pynative.com/python-database-connection-pooling-with-mysql/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **python-mysql-pool**
https://github.com/LuciferJack/python-mysql-pool

so easy config and use support multi database and support dynamic pool and fixed pool.

```
step:1

"""
file:mysql_config.py change to your db config
"""
db_config = {
    'local': {
        'host': "10.95.130.118", 'port': 8899,
        'user': "root", 'passwd': "123456",
        'db': "marry", 'charset': "utf8",
        'pool': {
            #use = 0 no pool else use pool
            "use":1,
            # size is >=0,  0 is dynamic pool
            "size":0,
            #pool name
            "name":"local",
        }
    },
    'poi': {
        'host': "10.95.130.***", 'port': 8787,
        'user': "lujunxu", 'passwd': "****",
        'db': "poi_relation", 'charset': "utf8",
        'pool': {
            #use = 0 no pool else use pool
            "use":0,
            # size is >=0,  0 is dynamic pool
            "size":0,
            #pool name
            "name":"poi",
        }
    },
}

step:2

"""
Note:create your own table
"""

step:3 (example show below)

"""
pool size special operation
"""
def query_pool_size():
    job_status = 2
    _sql = "select *  from master_job_list j  where j.job_status  in (%s) "
    _args = (job_status,)
    task = query(db_config['local'], _sql,_args)
    logging.info("query_npool method query_npool result is %s ,input _data is %s ", task , _args)
    return

"""
single query
"""
def query_npool():
    job_status = 2
    _sql = "select *  from master_job_list j  where j.job_status  !=%s "
    _args = (job_status,)
    task = query_single(db_config['local'], _sql,_args)
    logging.info("query_npool method query_npool result is %s ,input _data is %s ", task , _args)
    return

"""
insert
"""
def insert(nlp_rank_id,hit_query_word):
    #add more args
    _args = (nlp_rank_id,hit_query_word)
    _sql = """INSERT INTO nlp_rank_poi_online (nlp_rank_id,hit_query_word,rank_type,poi_list,poi_raw_list,article_id,city_id,status,create_time,version,source_from) VALUES (%s,%s,%s, %s, %s,%s, %s,%s, %s,%s,%s)"""
    affect = insertOrUpdate(db_config['local'], _sql, _args)
    logging.info("insert method insert result is %s ,input _data is %s ", affect , _args)
    return

"""
update
"""
def update(query_word,query_id):
    _args = (query_word,query_id)
    _sql = """update nlp_rank  set query_word = %s  WHERE  id = %s"""
    affect = insertOrUpdate(db_config['local'], _sql, _args)
    logging.info("update method update result is %s ,input _data is %s ", affect , _args)
    return
```